Converse of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?
The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma states the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}: L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\to C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$. The proof can be find in Grafakos or Duoandikoetxea's books. However, none of them consider the converse case: if $ f\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\hat f\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, does this implies $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$? If not, is there any counterexample for this clam?

is $\mathcal S'$ Schwartz space?

@SineoftheTime Yes.

The "soft" answer is: $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are not isomorphic Banach spaces; $\mathcal F$ is injective and continuous, therefore (by Banach-Steinhaus) it is not surjective $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\to C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
